Creating QUERY Drop Down List to Filter Data in Google Sheets with an Image
I am attempting to build a question bank in Google Sheets that have certain characteristics attached to the question (type of question, topic covered, level of difficulty). I want to create a sheet where I can use data validation drop downs to filter my question bank to show questions with the desired characteristic. The example I used was finding a question that is type "G" (for Geometry), topic covered is Law of Sines and the level of difficulty is a #51-60.
I used the following just to test if I could statically generate the questions I wanted (will move on to making it dynamic later):
=QUERY('Question Bank'!A1:J, "SELECT * WHERE D='G' AND G='law of sines' AND J='#51-60'",1)

however, in my 'Question Bank' sheet, the first column contains images, which I found does not work with the QUERY function. What is another way of achieving a similar result but allowing it to pull in the image from my 'Question Bank' sheet?


You may try with the filter function:
=filter('Question Bank'!A:J,'Question Bank'!D:D="G",'Question Bank'!G:G="law of sines",'Question Bank'!J:J="#51-60")


Okay, this works to generate my image. Now I am working on actually making it dynamic. What I have are three sheets - Question Finder (this is where I'm trying to create the drop downs with filtering), Question Bank, and Categorizations & Topics List. I have cells A2:C2 in Question Finder with drop downs linked to the C & TL sheet. So can I just change this function to: =FILTER('Question Bank'!A:J,
'Question Bank'!D:D = A2,
'Question Bank'!G:G = B2,
'Question Bank'!J:J = C2)

yes you can replace with cell address

When I attempted that, it just said Error
No matches are found in FILTER evaluation. I double checked that there are no data mismatches, and I'm certain my drop downs are linked back to the Categorizations sheet, etc.

Share a test sheet showcasing your inputs & expected output (manually entered). You can also use the anonymous blank sheet maker

I'll do that when I have a chance. I do think one issue I've discovered is that it will only produce a result if all three criteria are matched. Is there a way to change this so I can have it show if criteria A or criteria B or criteria C are matches if that makes sense? Like I want to be able to leave two of the three criteria blank and have it populate all results that just fit into the one criteria I chose rather than necessarily having to narrow it down super specifically.

I believe I figured it out, I rewrote the filter with + between my conditions so just "at least one" was fulfilled rather than requiring them all. As shown here:
=filter('Question Bank'!A2:J,('Question Bank'!G2:G=A2)+('Question Bank'!D2:D=B2)+('Question Bank'!J2:J=C2))
